# How to handle return value when no object found

Tags: java, object, methods, find

I have here the following piece of code, it is designed to find and return a product object, using a string input to compare with names of all products.

```
public Product find(String input){

    for(int i = 0; i <Products.size();i++)
    {
         if(input ==Products.get(i).getName()){

         return Products.get(i);
        }   
    }   
}
```

I am having two problems with it.

A) The return value is inside the IF statement, so the main method find() does not have a return value. therefore I am receiving an error message about this.

B) If the user types in the name of a product that does not exist, then no product will be found, in 
   which it shouldn't return anything, but I am not sure how to do this. The result is currently being 
   used to remove products, so if it passes a null product object to be removed this would probably cause an error output in the remove method.

I am new to programming so my apologies if this is a novice question, any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: You should use `equals()` method to compare String values: `if(input.equals(Products.get(i).getName()))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(A) and (B) are really just the same problem. :-)

You need to have code after the loop that does one of two things when no match is found:

1. Throws an exception, or
2. Returns `null`

...or return an `Optional` as [Andreas shows you in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59757232/157247).

Returning `null` is standard if not finding a match is common and normal. Throwing an exception is standard if not finding a match is unusual and unexpected.

---

A couple of other notes on that code:

1. Don't use `==` to compare strings, use `equals`; [details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)
2. I assume `Products` is either an instance variable (field) or a static variable. If so, it shouldn't be initially-capped. Standard Java naming conventions have instance and static variables start with a lower case letter.
3. If `Products` is an instance variable, I strongly recommend using `this.` to access it (`this.Products`, not just `Products`), although it's a matter of style; Java *does* allow you to leave it off.
4. If `Products` is an array or a `List` (given the `size()` method, it looks like a list), you'd probably be better off using the enhanced `for` loop.
5. Excessive use of blank lines is discouraged. Again, just a matter of style. :-)
6. It's best to be consistent with your placement of curly braces (`{}`) (at the end of the line, or on its own on the next line, but not both in the same code). :-)

Taking all of the above into account, assuming `Products` is an instance variable:

```
public Product find(String input) {
    for (Product product : this.products) {
        if (input.equals(product.getName())) {
            return product;
        }   
    }   
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Very solid answer! 

Comment: Thank you very much indeed for your help with this, I appreciate the extra effort in helping to improve the overall code!  Is it correct to think that once the return statement is read - whether inside the for loop or not - the overall find method ends? 
Also I have never seen this code (Product product : this.products), understand it loops through all array elements however could point me towards a source explaining which parts of the code does what ?

Comment: @InitialisingAttributes Correct, when a `return` statement is executed, no other code in the method will be executed *(except `finally` blocks)*. --- `for (Product product : this.products)` is known as an *enhanced* `for` loop. See *any Java guide* on `for` loops for more detail, e.g. [The Java™ Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) or [GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/loops-in-java/) or [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_for_loop.asp) or ...

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way to return nothing, as of Java 8, is to return an [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html):

```
public Optional<Product> find(String input) {
    for (Product product : products) {
        if (product.getName().equals(input)) {
            return Optional.of(product);
        }
    }
    return Optional.empty();
}
```

This forces the caller to check if something was returned.

For more information, see e.g. [Guide To Java 8 Optional](https://www.baeldung.com/java-optional).

---

For pre-Java 8, or just to do it old-style, return a `null` value:

```
public Product find(String input) {
    for (Product product : products) {
        if (product.getName().equals(input)) {
            return product;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

It is still up to the caller to check if something was returned, i.e. to check whether `null` is returned. It is however too easy for the caller to forget to do that, which is why use of `Optional` is preferred.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest using the Optional class for achieving your goals. Your code can easily be replaced by this code. Assuming that you have a list of products, the following code can be used :

```
public Optional<Product> find(String name) {
    List<Product> products = productDao.fetchAll();
    return products.stream().filter(p -> StringUtils.equals(p.name, name)).findFirst().orElseThrow(<Insert some excpeption builder>);
}
```

Comment: Why `StringUtils.equals(...)`? What library is that even from? Why not the built-in  [`Objects.equals(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#equals-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-)?

Comment: What's the point of using `Optional` if you're never going to return an empty optional, but throw an exception instead?